# Does Spring Data MongoDB support enums?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

For Java enum type, I learn that there are two solutions for MongoDB: [serialization](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/01/3-ways-to-serialize-java-enums/) and [using Jackson’s ObjectMapper](http://www.ikelin.com/java-enum-mongodb/). Can the MongoRepository work with an enum data type with either of those approaches or I have to write a customized repository?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, Spring Data MongoDB supports enums. Just use them in your domain model.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. After my posted my question, I wrote a unit test last night and all tests were passed. I should do more work before posting anything. Now, I need to figure out how to make a Java enum data with Javascript code. That is another story.

Comment: Does that assume that the enum values are strings and the mongodb field is a string and it does a case sensitive match?

Comment: I've tried this, but it says it "didn't find a PersistentEntity" for the enum. Thoughts?

Comment: You of course can't store them as is but only as property of a domain class.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this point further? I opened a question on this in particular, if you could check it out that would be awesome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465862/spring-data-mongo-cannot-find-persistententity-for-enum

Answer (score 7):

Spring Data Mongodb can serialize enum into string using enum's name as value. Let's say, it uses the second approach from the article http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/01/3-ways-to-serialize-java-enums/. IMHO this can't be taken seriously, because the only correct way to store enums in the database is the approach #3 from the same article, let me cite it: "This approach involves assigning a an explicit user defined value to each enum constant and defining a toValue() and fromValue() methods on the enum to do the serialization and deserialization.". So, Spring Data Mongodb does not support enums.