# Spring Data Mongo cannot find PersistentEntity for Enum

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-mongodb

Edit: I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972455/does-spring-data-mongodb-support-enums), but the only 2 answers contradict each other, and there was not enough information to address my use case.

I am trying to use Spring Data Mongo to load records from a collection. One of the fields within those records is an Enum, defined as such:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Action {
    APPROVED("Approved"),
    SAVED("Saved"),
    CORRECTED("Corrected");

    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    static Action findValue(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(Action.values()).filter(v -> v.name.equals(name)).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

This should define enums to be serialized and deserialized according to a JSON representation: `{"name": "Saved"}` for example.

Jackson seems to be working fine, since I threw an API call at it and told it to expect an `Action` type, and it read the enum without any issues.

```java
public void save(@RequestBody @Valid Action action) {
    System.out.println(action.getName());
} // successfully prints the name of whatever Action I give
```

However, when I try to read an object with an Action field using Spring Data Mongo, I get the following:

```
Expected to read Document Document{{name=Corrected}} into type class package.structure.for.some.proprietary.stuff.constants.Action but didn't find a PersistentEntity for the latter!
```

So I'm thinking Spring Data Mongo just can't make heads or tails of these enums for whatever reason. But I'm not sure how to help it register that as a PersistentEntity. The main class of my Spring Boot app is in package `package.structure.for.some.proprietary.stuff` and is annotated as such:

```java
@ComponentScan("package.structure")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
```

The object in particular I'm trying to read is defined by this POJO:

```java
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;

import package.structure.for.some.proprietary.stuff.constants.Action;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "timeStamp",
    "action",
})
@Data
@Document(collection = "sample_coll")
public class Sample {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id = null;

    @JsonProperty("timeStamp")
    @NonNull
    private Date timeStamp;
    @JsonProperty("action")
    @NonNull
    private Action action;
}
```

and is queried from the collection with a MongoRepository:

```java
public interface SampleRepository extends MongoRepository<Sample, String> {

}
```

using `SampleRepository.findAll();`

So my big question is, how do I get Spring Data Mongo to recognize this enum Action as a PersistentEntity?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet? I got the same problem since I updated my jvm version to 11.

Answer (score -2):

Try @Enumerated

```java
@Enumerated
@JsonProperty("action")
@NonNull
private Action action;
```

Comment: @Enumerated is a JPA annotation, which is for relational databases. MongoDB is a NoSQL database. Can you provide an example of this working?

Comment: In my project, I use nothing, just plan enum. And it works. So I support the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972455/does-spring-data-mongodb-support-enums